# Create infinite loop

Tags: perl, loops, while-loop

This script is looping only once. I want to make it an infinite loop.

```
open( FILE, "<$ARGV[0]" );

if ( $LOOP == 1) {

    while ( <FILE> ) {

        if ( $. == $LOOP ) {
            next
        };
   }
}

while ( <FILE> ) {
    $LIST = $_;
    print "$LIST"; 
}
```

I want make it looping back to the first line, like this

```
abc
abcd
abcde
abc
abcd
abcde
...
```

Comment: What is your question? `$LOOP` is never defined so the `if` is never executed and your program is effectively just the final`while`/`print` loop

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`. At the very least, it will find some scoping issues in your program. /// Also, avoid using global variables (`open(FILE, ...`). Use lexical variables instead. (`open(my $FILE, ...)`).

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap what you want to loop with `while (1) { ... }`.

Cleaned up, you get:

```
my $qfn = $ARGV[0];

while (1) {
   open(my $fh, '<', $qfn)
      or die("Can't open \"$qfn\": $!\n");

   while (<$fh>) {
      print;
   }
}
```

A very minor optimization is to avoid re-opening the file, seeking instead.

```
use Fcntl qw( SEEK_SET );

my $qfn = $ARGV[0];

open(my $fh, '<', $qfn)
   or die("Can't open \"$qfn\": $!\n");

while (1) {
   while (<$fh>) {
      print;
   }

   seek($fh, 0, SEEK_SET);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `seek` to go reset the position in the filehandle. `eof` is true if the filehandle is on the last line.

```
open FILE,'<',$ARGV[0];
while (my $line = <FILE>) {
    print $line;
    if (eof) {
        seek FILE,0,0;
    }
}
```

Comment: @andrew99 you can express your thanks by accepting the answer :)

Answer (score -2):

You can try something like this...

```
my ( $filename ) = @ARGV;

while ( 1 )
{
    open my $fh, '<', $filename or die $!;
    my @lines = <$fh>;
    close $fh;
    print @lines;
}
```

It should open the file, read it in, close it, print contents and then repeat.

Comment: Thnks for the respond,but i want to print it as variable not as array.anyway tht script doesn't work :D

Comment: `my @lines = <$filename>`? Please don't post untested code if you can possibly avoid it.

Comment: Sorry about that. I typed it too quickly and used $filename instead of $fh. Simple mistake. I edited the original code to fix it.

Comment: Arrays are variable. If you mean convert the Array to a Scalar then you can do so by adding the line my $variable = join(q{}, @lines); and changing print @lines to print $variable